# Is it possible to view Career Profile information for Overwatch 2 only?

Tags: overwatch-2

Overwatch 2's Career Profile page has brought over all old stats from the original Overwatch. Some things are bugged, like previous Competitive results, as my only recorded competitive seasons have the exact same SR stats across three seasons. I looked thoroughly through all the statistics and history information, but I can't find any way to restrict information to Overwatch 2 only. Is this possible in the current state of the game?